# Automate copyright year in footer.vm of email template in velocity files

Tags: java, date, sap-commerce-cloud, expert-system

For copyright year I have added various syntax like 
${ctx.messages.getMessage(${ctx.dateTool.getyear()})}
But it's printing same as it is
Even tried with various others 
${ctx.dateTool.getyear()}
${ctx.dateTool.getyear('yyyy')}

Can anyone  help on this velocity templates copyright year ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, ${ctx.dateTool.year()} should work. At least it should call the dateTool.getYear() method.

Why do you fetch the year from the Message bundle? Typically you would add it as a parameter:
${ctx.messages.getMessage('yourmessagecode',${ctx.dateTool.year()})}

In the message bundle:
yourmessagecode=Copyright {0}

Btw according to DateTool class:

```
public Integer getYear() {
    return this.getYear(this.getCalendar());
}

public Integer getYear(Object date) {
    return this.getValue(1, date);
}
```

If you call getYear with parameter it expects an date, not a formatting defintion.

Comment: Yes ${ctx.dateTool.getyear()} this syntax is working in velocity file, but while I defined in proper footer.vm inside various tags then displays same why this is happen in velocity files